# Remove node_view rendered node's title link

Tags: nodes

I am using the code below to add a form to my node. This renders a page with the node and form on it. Apparently, the node is rendered with its title as a link. I would like to have the node's title without a link. So I tried to change `$node->content`, but there seems to be no value that determines that the node title is a link. how do I change this with code?

```
$form = array();
$node = node_load(24)
$form['offer_form'] = array(
  '#value' => drupal_get_form('dt_offer_entry_form', $node),
  '#weight' => 10
);
$node->content = $form;
return node_view($node);
```

Comment: that title/link behavior is normally dealt with inside of your theme's `node.tpl.php` template.  Often it is based upon whether it is a full page view vs a teaser view.  Going in and creating a specific one just for this content type, eg, `node--TYPE.tpl.php` (D7) or `node-TYPE.tpl.php` (D6), might be the quickest way to deal with this.

Comment: You could also look at calling `node_view()` with different `$view_mode` (D7) or `$teaser`/`$page` (D6) arguments to coerce different behavior if your theme supports it.  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7 for more info

Comment: This worked for me:  
    $node_view = node_view($node, FALSE, TRUE);
    return '<h2 class="title">Voorstel indienen</h2>' . $node_view;

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64241/remove-node-view-rendered-nodes-title-link/202196#comment69771_64241), this code worked for the OP.

```
$node_view = node_view($node, FALSE, TRUE);
return '<h2 class="title">Voorstel indienen</h2>' . $node_view;
```